# KivyMD how to get focused textfield's id using on_focus event

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I would like to turn on the phone's camera when the user focuses on barcode textfield.

However, on_focus event is triggered, even if you you focus on another textfield. I somehow have to make sure the focused textfield is the barcode textfield. How do i do that?

on_double_tap event seems to solve my problem but i want to turn on the camera on one tap.

Here is my related .kv code:

```
GridLayout:
    rows: 4
    cols: 1
    row_default_height: 40
    padding: [10,70,10,10]
    spacing: 0

    MDTextField:
        id: txt_barcode_3
        hint_text: "Barkod"
        on_focus: root.barcode_camera_insert()
        
    MDTextField:
        id: txt_reference_3
        hint_text: "Referans"
        
    MDTextField:
        id: txt_productname_3
        hint_text: "Ürün Adı"
        
    MDRectangleFlatButton
        id: btn_save_3
        text: "Kaydet"
        font_size: "20sp"
        size_hint: 1,0  
        on_press: root.add_barcode()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on_focus` event is triggered whenever `focus` changes, even if it changes from `True` to `False`. So your `root.barcode_camera_insert()` is called in either case. I haven't tested this but try:

```
on_focus: root.barcode_camera_insert() if self.focus else None
```